# NodeJS on server thats running multiple sites

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm new to publishing website.

So my situation is this, in our school, we have a website, then I've done some project and we want to merge it to our school website.

```
www.schoolwebsite.com/myproject
```

So we decided to make it something like that. They're running WordPress website, and my project is built on using MEAN technology (not the one on mean.io).
So I transferred all my project files into their FileZilla thing. Then on the server, we installed NodeJS and MongoDB.

On my server file (index.js), I'm listening to port 3000, so my angularjs will talk to the www.schoolwebsite.com:3000 to get the API's. I was able to get it to talk, but the problem is, there is also another website that's been hosted on the same server:

```
Server --> 2 websites (www.schoolwebsite.com and www.somewebsite.com)
```

Both of them have 3000 port open (well because they're on the same server).

```
www.schoolwebsite.com:3000
www.somewebsite.com:3000
123.456.789.123:3000 <-- Example Server IP
```

So the guy showed me that this is whats happening when I run the "node index.js" it listens to port 3000.

My question is, is there a way in NodeJS to only open the port 3000 on www.schoolwebsite.com?

Is this a security issue? Having both port 3000 on the sites? What's the best practice on this one?

Comment: Are you trying to get one website to have separate pages load from two different servers?

Comment: yes sir! my website will use NodeJS. and they're not using NodeJS

Comment: I doubt that the problem you're facing has to do with which ports you're trying to get these things to listen on. Look at the routes the server that's hosting the original site is serving. You can probably have it call your server from a specific route.

Comment: @GlenPierce so is this alright? When i run the node server, it will open the port 3000 on both websites? On my project i dont have a problem, but is this safe?

Comment: I'm confused a bit. Is it working? If it's working, then it sounds like your question is security-related, in which case, I would recommend asking this question on the stack exchange website dedicated to security, they would have a much better understanding of the nuances that might arise here. I don't think it's a problem since you have to have some communication channel open and the specific port number is largely irrelevant.